# Contract transaction not appearing

Tags: solidity

I interacted with my smart contract's function, looks like it went through, attached is the tx_receipt, but the contract doesnt see  transaction and the contract has not updated as it should.

contract: https://polygonscan.com/address/0xb6506ee5F7cF6802eF7D1B651E7f2A5af1B6949a

```
tx_receipt: AttributeDict({'blockHash': HexBytes('0x0e3e4e2b0e37d65c17e0e042acfeb5ea821ead6fb65951a11930dfc5afb5887e'), 'blockNumber': 40907913, 'contractAddress': None, 'cumulativeGasUsed': 11308700, 'effectiveGasPrice': 444056718673, 'from': '0x63C18042Ff056493c62bc74d04A32F03a5813798', 'gasUsed': 165824, 'logs': [AttributeDict({'address': '0xb6506ee5F7cF6802eF7D1B651E7f2A5af1B6949a', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x0e3e4e2b0e37d65c17e0e042acfeb5ea821ead6fb65951a11930dfc5afb5887e'), 'blockNumber': 40907913, 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000063c18042ff056493c62bc74d04a32f03a5813798000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000210e', 'logIndex': 267, 'removed': False, 'topics': [HexBytes('0x40c340f65e17194d14ddddb073d3c9f888e3cb52b5aae0c6c7706b4fbc905fac')], 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x2e269c621567a052c3190aa671114d82416ca8ca974751954c2884bac59437fc'), 'transactionIndex': 61}), AttributeDict({'address': '0xb6506ee5F7cF6802eF7D1B651E7f2A5af1B6949a', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x0e3e4e2b0e37d65c17e0e042acfeb5ea821ead6fb65951a11930dfc5afb5887e'), 'blockNumber': 40907913, 'data': '0x000000000000000000000000f48b3847936bb9cc96a3cfb0f01eb1057ccfa34900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001bd', 'logIndex': 268, 'removed': False, 'topics': [HexBytes('0x40c340f65e17194d14ddddb073d3c9f888e3cb52b5aae0c6c7706b4fbc905fac')], 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x2e269c621567a052c3190aa671114d82416ca8ca974751954c2884bac59437fc'), 'transactionIndex': 61}), AttributeDict({'address': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x0e3e4e2b0e37d65c17e0e042acfeb5ea821ead6fb65951a11930dfc5afb5887e'), 'blockNumber': 40907913, 'data': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012da1d13b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005013d842310b68120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002636f3bcf20e5981f0c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005000fe251d5b68120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002636f4ea93df9481f0c', 'logIndex': 269, 'removed': False, 'topics': [HexBytes('0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63'), HexBytes('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010'), HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000063c18042ff056493c62bc74d04a32f03a5813798'), HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000e7e2cb8c81c10ff191a73fe266788c9ce62ec754')], 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x2e269c621567a052c3190aa671114d82416ca8ca974751954c2884bac59437fc'), 'transactionIndex': 61})], 'logsBloom': HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000800000000000000000000000080000000000200000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000008001000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000200000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000081000000080000000000000000000000100000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000'), 'status': 1, 'to': '0xb6506ee5F7cF6802eF7D1B651E7f2A5af1B6949a', 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x2e269c621567a052c3190aa671114d82416ca8ca974751954c2884bac59437fc'), 'transactionIndex': 61, 'type': '0x2'})
```

[image: contract on polygonscan]

[image: tx_receipt]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a transaction receipt but you are unable to find the transaction in a blockchain explorer, it is possible that the transaction was not included in the blockchain. It could happen due network congestion, in which case it will takes long to be processed. Other possible reason is that you execute the transaction in the wrong chain.
Please try to provide the transaction receipt as text instead of a screenshot because it becomes very difficult to review the data in that way. Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

The block 40907913 has already been produced and your transactions were included there. I'm not one hundred percent sure why this happens, but it is not uncommon for blockchain networks to experience delays or congestion during periods of high network activity, such as during periods of heavy trading or when a large number of transactions are being processed. These delays can result in longer confirmation times for transactions and may cause the block number to be delayed in being produced.

[image]

Comment: receipt is there as text now

Comment: In the transaction receipt you provided, there is a block number (40907913) that has not yet been produced by the Polygon network. If a transaction is submitted when there are no available blocks to include it in, the transaction will remain in the pending transaction pool until the assigned block is produced.  You can see from this link that the block in which the transaction was included has not yet been produced: https://polygonscan.com/block/countdown/40907913